# Regex to hide first two IP address octets

Tags: regex, powershell

I have gotten to the following regex command to 'x' the first two octets of IP addresses, using powershell;

`-Replace '(?=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d', 'x'`

On the following dataset;

```
10.101.11.11
101.11.11.11
2003.12.11
```

I get;

```
xx.xxx.11.11
xxx.xx.11.11
2xxx.12.11
```

It formats the IP addresses correctly as required but I can't seem to get it to ignore dates with . in them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\b)\d(?=\d{0,2}\.\d{1,3}\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bvxCRY/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\b)` - word boundary or the end of the previous successful match
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?=\d{0,2}\.\d{1,3}\.)` - a position that is immediately followed with zero to two digits + `.`  + one to three digits + `.`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
-Replace '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})



Write-Host $('2023.12.12' -Replace '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})', 'xxx.xxx.$1')
2023.12.12

Write-Host $('202.21.32.1' -Replace '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})', 'xxx.xxx.$1')
xxx.xxx.32.1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, thats a solid answer however an IP of 10.10.10.10 would end up as xxx.xxx.10.10, Those two extra 'x' can start to skew data in tables. The response from Wiktor accounts for xx or xxx and changes as appropriate so is a better solution for what I needed - BUT yours is alot easier to read/understand and I can see where I was going wrong with my original attempt.